# Composer and shared hosting

Tags: composer-php

Really struggling with Composer, and a class I am trying to use that needs it.

I have composer on the shared host (or I believe I do, given another class works (PHPOffice))

For that the /vendor directory is in the HTDOCS folder with COMPOSER and PHPOFFICE under there, along with the autoload.php.

So then I downloaded lablnet/Encryption from php-download which gave me the same directory structure that is in the existing /vendor dir, but I am fairly sure overwriting the files will stop PHPOffice working...

Could someone please let me know how I might be able to get the two things to co-reside?  And where to drop the downloaded Ecryption class...

I would love to follow the install instructions, but on the shared host, I cant run the composer require command.

Hoping for help as all I would like to be able to do is use the Encryption class.

Comment: What does your composer.json look like? Which composer commands did you run?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...  And apologies but I was meaning to post the solution...

In the end i have found out that Composer isn't 'supported' with my shared hosting provider...  So as discussed above, I found php-download.

Once I got the zip down, it was then a case of playing with locations of the files, to find they have to be located within the root of the site.

I have also since realised that if you want to run multiple packages on the same site, then you need to use the 'Project' function at php-download, which will bring everything into one composer.json and lock file for you.

So, in sort this was relatively simple to fix, but you have to know that the files need to be taken out of the 'package' dir so that you have the VENDOR dir at the level below your main site files, and that's the place for the .JSON and .LOCK files.